# Odoo 12- Is it possible to change the number of select options of a selection field based on value of another field?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I am developing a module for processing Loan Request for our business and I need to have different select options for a selection field based on another field's value. Is it possible to change the select options of this field based on other field value? I tried to use `@api.onchange` but I couldn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It's possible, however, to change the domain for a relational field:

```
@api.onchange("field1")
def _onchange_field1(self):
    desired_domain = self._get_domain_for_field2()
    return {"domain": {"field2_id": desired_domain}}
```

That would possibly fit your use case if you use a `Many2one` instead of a `Selection` field.

Comment: In case of Many2one you're right, but I don't have Many2one and I should use a selection field.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but the answer is no: you can't change selections in an onchange.